# Print star pattern in c++

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm having trouble finding out how to start with a problem that asks to print for an integer, suppose 3,

```
*
**
*
***
*
**
*
```

And so far I only have

```
void print(int n)
{
    if (n < 1) {
        return;
    }
    if (n == 1) {
        cout << "*" << endl;
        return;
    }

    print_star(n - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "*";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

And the output I see is

```
*
**
***
```

I cannot think of a code to print that pattern.

Comment: ... Where's your code and what's the problem?

Comment: please add more detail to this question, as this doesnt tell us enough to understand the problem and help you.

Comment: I have some difficulties to understand why this question was closed as beeing not focused enough ????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to print again the case `n-1`after printing the `n`stars.

For example, for `n = 2`, adding this new print will replace

```
*
**
```

by

```
*
**
*
```

Same for higher values of `n`

```
#include    <iostream>

void print_stars (int n) {
    if (n < 1) return;
    if (n == 1) {
        std::cout << '*' << "\n";
    } else {
        print_stars (n-1);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) std::cout << '*';
        std::cout << "\n";
        print_stars (n-1);
    }
}

int main() {
    print_stars (3);
}
```

Comment: but how does adding the case n-1 at the end make the pattern like that? I don't quite understand..

Comment: I updated the answer. Hope it is enough.